# Basic local search engine - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, search-engine, tokenize

This is for an assignment at my university where I have to program a basic search engine using Python 2.7.10.

My search engine needs to look at a collection of documents in a folder on my computer, open them, strip some punctuation, make everything lowercase and make an inverted index for each token in the documents. The index would be stored as dictionaries with the key as the token and the value as a list of documents containing the token. Example: The token "æble" is found in document 1, document 2 and document 5. 
Then the user should be able to type in just a single word and the program should then procure a list of documents containing that single word.

I use the os, codecs and sys modules.

First I'd like to define my functions. I have begun with defining the function the program will use to open the documents and at the same time make it lowercase.
The path will be specified later in the program by raw_input.

```
def open_doc(path):
    docfile = codecs.open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    doclist = docfile.read().lower().split()
    docfile.close()
    return doclist
```

Then, I have my function to tokenize single words which I'll apply to the user queries.

```
def tokenize(word):
    tokenword = word.strip(',.-?!=()')
    return tokenword
```

Now, even more tokenizing. Here, I try to append my tokenizing function to the dictionaries which will contain the different documents.

```
def tokedict(dict):
    tokenizeddict = {}
    for key in dict:
        tokenizeddict[key] = []
        for item in dict[key]:
            tokenizeddict[key].append(tokenize(item))
    return tokenizeddict
```

Now, I have a function which should invert my index. The values would be turned into keys and the keys turned into values.

```
def invert_dict(d):
    inverse = dict()
    for key in d:
        val = d[key]
        if val not in inverse:
            inverse[val] = [key]
        else:
            inverse[val].append(key)
    return inverse
```

I think that works as intended.

So, that is my main functions which my main program will have to call upon.
When the user opens the program, the user will be prompted to choose a path to a folder where the documents are stored in order to definde the variable called 'path'.

```
path = raw_input('please specify the path to the folder you would like to search in: ')
```

then, the program will create a dictionary for the index which will be created using the above functions.

First, the empty index

```
index = dict()
```

then the function filling up the index with the documents from the chosen path.

```
for document in os.listdir(path):
    index[str(document)] = open_doc(path+document)
```

That is basically what I've got up until now. I'm kinda stuck on the program.
I have a search function and for some reason even that won't work properly.

It goes as follows:

```
def User_search():
    searchword = raw_input('Please type 1 word to search for: ')
    searchword = searchword.lower()
    searchword = searchword.strip(',.!?()=')
    return searchword
```

So, my final question now is this:
How can I connect these pieces and end up with a program that'll do these following functions:

Scan a folder by a path given by the user
Tokenize and make lowercase the contents of documents in the folder - 
Make an inverted index - 
Make the user first choose a path to a folder; then make the user type in a searchword - 
call the functions in the right order - 
Give a result containing a list (of some sort) of documents containing the searchword.

The final function, I imagine, will be something like this:

```
for key in inverse:
    if searchword in key
        print 'Your searchword' + searchword + 'has been found in the following documents' + value
    if searchword not in key
        print 'no documents have been found containing your searchword'
```

But this is just an idea.

I look forward to receiving any sorts of help. It took me more than an hour just to type in this question so I hope it is easy to understand for you. If not, I will try to clarify.

Kindest regards

Comment: `searchword.lower`. You forgot to actually call the method. There's a couple of other basic typos, (missing parenthesis, etc). Another quick point, there's a lot of extra information here. We really don't need much more than the code that doesn't work, a quick description of what it's supposed to do, and the error. You may want to reread [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax error here:

```
tokenizeddict[key].append(tokenize(item)
```

Is because you're missing a parentheses at the end. Should be:

```
tokenizeddict[key].append(tokenize(item))
```

Also "dict" is python type, not an appropriate variable name - I would definitely rename that.

You're getting `builtin_function_or_method has no attribute 'strip'` because of this:

```
searchword = searchword.lower
```

You're just accessing the method, not actually calling it. You want to do:

```
searchword = searchword.lower()
```

I hope this helps. FYI in the future it would be more appropriate to break this into individual questions about specific errors. If you want to discuss your program as a whole once those errors are resolved, check out CodeReview.